# Deferred query with where clause being built in foreach/for

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

While troubleshooting a bug I ran into this. It seems to be due to deferred execution and the query is using the last value of variable keyword. What is the recommended pattern to solve this.

```
var query = from c in dbContext.Cars
            select c;

var keywords = new string[] { "Clean", "Car" };

foreach (var keyword in keywords)
{
    query = query.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(keyword));
}

var cars = query.ToList();
```

Results in query like this (note the value of both parameters is "Car")

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[CarID] AS [MID], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
FROM [dbo].[Cars] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[Name] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE N''~'') AND ([Extent1].[Name] LIKE @p__linq__1 ESCAPE N''~'')
',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__1 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'%Car%',@p__linq__1=N'%Car%'
```

Debugging in LINQPad also shows same query

```
DECLARE p__linq__0 NVarChar(1) = '%Car%'
DECLARE p__linq__1 NVarChar(1) = '%Car%'

SELECT 
[Extent1].[CarID] AS [MID], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
FROM [dbo].[Cars] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[Name] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE N'~') AND ([Extent1].[Name] LIKE @p__linq__1 ESCAPE N'~')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's due to the way variables are captured in anonymous functions. Change this:

```
foreach (var keyword in keywords)
{
    query = query.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(keyword));
}
```

to this:

```
foreach (var keyword in keywords)
{
    var copy = keyword;
    query = query.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(copy));
}
```

and it should work. See [Eric Lippert's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) for more details. The behaviour is changing for C# 5, so you won't need to worry at that point.

Note, however, that you could also try to let LINQ do this for you:

```
var query = dbContext.Cars.Where(c => keywords.All(key => c.Name.Contains(key));
```

I'm pretty sure that would work for `Any` (an "OR" effectively) but I don't know for sure whether it will work with `All`. Work a try...

Comment: Thanks @Jon, it works fine. Thanks for Eric's blog link too as it explains it clearly. This is a very short version of the actual query building in a rather large code so I will have to confirm if Any/All can be used. Thanks for those too.

Comment: While All works in an isolated query (the one I have posted) when it is used in the actual query where there are other joins and conditions, the EF generated query becomes nasty and takes forever to execute. That might be the reason for the change to begin with and a big. Sticking to foreach with creation of new closures variable inside.